# In how many ways $A_n$ can we cover a $2 \times n$ rectangle with $1 \times 2$ and $2 \times 2$ polyominoes?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, tiling, polyomino

This is my answer:

(if rotations are allowed)
Let An be the number of ways to completely cover a 2 times n checkerboard with 1x2 and 2x2 dominoes

There 3 conditions:
The upper right corner can be covered with a vertical 1x2 domino, so there An-1 ways to completely cover the checkerboard.
The upper right corner can be covered with two horizontal 1x2 domino, so there An-2 ways to completely cover the checkerboard.
The upper right corner can be covered with a 2x2 domino, so there An-2 ways to completely cover the checkerboard.

Derived from the 3 conditions we have:
    An = A(n-1)+2A(n-2) for n>=2
with starting values A1 = 1 and A2 = 3

I want to ask if it is properly defined mathematically, especially for the conditions. Any advise will be appreciated.

Comment: [OEIS A001045](https://oeis.org/A001045)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the idea and recurrence are correct if rotations are allowed, but you should use MathJax to format.  Also, only $1 \times 2$ or $2 \times 1$ polyominoes are called dominoes. You could instead use $A_0=1$ (the empty tiling) and $A_1=1$ as the initial conditions. Then $A_2=A_1+2 A_0=1+2\cdot 1=3$ follows from the recurrence.  Now do you know how to solve this to find an explicit formula for $A(n)$?

Comment: I changed the initial conditions and I think the explicit formula is: 1/3((-1)^n+2^(1+n). Thank you for your time and assistance.